# Writing to two different Hbase versions?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Is it possible to write to two different hbase tables at the same time with different versions in each, on different clusters using hbase Java API but using only one client?

Comment: It depends what are those two different versions of HBase are. Please add more details to your question.

Comment: The old one is MapR cluster with version .94.13 of Hadoop & Hbase. The newer one is Cloudera with version 0.98.6-cdh5.3.0 of Hadoop & Hbase.  Event if I had to setup two clients that would be fine.  I just want to be able to write to both from my java app.  Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *theory* you can, but with much work. If the versions are compatible, you can use in the client the oldest version to connect both servers, using for each one a different `HConnection` (with different configuration each one) from `HConnectionManager`.

If your server versions are not compatible, you can't because of java's classes loading (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)  unless you start using something like OSGI or creating special classes loader, etc. Nothing easy at all. Almost always too much work for a poor payment.

From my experience, don't expect 0.9x to be compatible with 0.9(x+2), but test it. Maybe you are lucky...

Comment: Unfortunately, 0.94 is not compatible with 0.98. I think, your next option is to look into Thrift. Or you can upgrade your MapR cluster to 0.98